# SIDDIH SMTP SERVER ERROR Must issue a STARTTLS command first

Tags: siddhi

I am setting up a smtp server in SIDDIH, I use smtp.gmail.com with my user and password and I enabled the 'access to less secure apps' option

I am going to show the code but ofuscating my email account and password

```
@Source(type = 'http',
    receiver.url='http://0.0.0.0:8006/thresold',
    basic.auth.enabled='false',
    @map(type='json'))
define stream TransactionStream(creditCardNo string, country string, item string, quantity int, price double);

@sink(type='email',
  mail.smtp.starttls.enable = 'true',
  username ='testuser',
  address ='testuser@gmail.com',
  password= 'xxxx',
  subject='Alert for large value transaction: cardNo:{{creditCardNo}}',
  to='final_destination@domainx.com',
  port = '587',
  host = 'smtp.gmail.com',
  ssl.enable = 'false',
  auth = 'true', 
  @map(type='text'))
define stream AlertStream(creditCardNo string, country string, item string, quantity int, price double);

@info(name='query1') 
  from TransactionStream[quantity * price  > 5000]
  select *
  insert into AlertStream;
```

I get the error 'Must issue a STARTTLS command first'
I am trying with the Siddih single simulation and deploying and sending parameters via http post
I expect to be able to send email without the error with a smpt server.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried with below sink configuration and it worked. Please change accordingly and tryout. Please update the username, password, address and to attributes with proper values.

```
@sink(type = 'email', username = "${EMAIL_USERNAME}", 
address = "${SENDER_EMAIL_ADDRESS}", password = "${EMAIL_PASSWORD}", 
subject = "Upgrade API Subscription Tier", to = "{{userEmail}}", 
host = "smtp.gmail.com", port = "465", ssl.enable = "true", auth = "true", 
@map(type = 'text', @payload("XYZ")))
```

Comment: In summary the difference is:
ssl.enable = "true"
port = "465"
and remove mail.smtp.starttls.enable